# Headset replacement for Fit Bikes BMX

Tags: headset, bearings

My son has a Fit BMX bike, seems to be a normal 20" setup. However, the head tube appears to have an inside diameter of 1 3/8", and every BMX headset I'm seeing expects that diameter to be 1 1/4" ID. The headset offered on the fit website is 1 1/8". Is this a normal size? Does anyone know what headset would be proper for a replacement? Thanks